# Puppet dependency loop when needing to notify a service from a class that first needs the service to be running

Tags: puppet

I am trying to build a module that uses the usual install->config->service pattern but with a twist. After the service starts there is more configuration done via an admin API. Unfortunately the vendor product also then requires some of the results of that API invocation to be edited into some config XML files which requires a service restart. So I have install->config->service->admin->service which is of course a dependency loop. Is there a clean way to do this? I've resorted to having to exec{'/sbin/service ... restart'} in the admin class. Not clean at all:

```
anchor { 'pingfederate::begin': } ->
class { '::pingfederate::install': } ->
class { '::pingfederate::config': } ~>
class { '::pingfederate::service': } ->
class { '::pingfederate::admin': } ->
anchor { 'pingfederate::end': }
```

and then `exec {'/sbin/service pingfederate restart':}`

See https://github.com/n2ygk/puppet-pingfederate

Comment: Slightly less bad is to use a `service` resource and specify the `start/stop/status/restart` commands. You still get the intrinsic idempotency etc. of `service` resource and it is unique and slightly less hacky.

Comment: The sequence of steps you describe is crazy.  The service must be running before it can be (properly) configured, yet the configuration program cannot update the service dynamically?  Really?  Are you sure there isn't a simpler alternative, such as a TUI (already better) that doesn't require the service to be running first (jackpot!)?  Or can you maybe skip their configurator altogether, and write the needed config files directly?

Comment: They define a REST API to added a new datastore (for example) which is a JDBC connector. Then you have to take the identifier returned by that API call and stick it in a configuration XML file. I don't know why they don't just edit the XML file themselves, but it is what it is.

Comment: @MattSchuchard using a service resource causes the dependency loop.

Comment: @n2ygk You are confused by my suggestion. You can do the same service with a different title by specifying the commands manually.

Comment: @MattSchuchard - No, the service name is still the same. `Error: Evaluation Error: Error while evaluating a Resource Statement, Cannot alias Service[pingfederate admin restart] to ["pingfederate"] at /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/modules/pingfederate/manifests/admin.pp:20; resource ["Service", "pingfederate"] already declared at /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/modules/pingfederate/manifests/service.pp:4 at /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/modules/pingfederate/manifests/admin.pp:20:3 on node localhost.localdomain
`

Comment: @n2ygk Since you are still confused I can write it out as an answer, but I don't think it really qualifies as a true solution, but rather as a less bad workaround.

Comment: @MattSchuchard would love to see your solution since the title is not what the service resources compare on but the actual service name.

Comment: @n2ygk Actually both are checked for uniqueness. Check out the documentation for resources and read up on uniqueness for `title` and `namevar`. I will get the less bad workaround typed up soon.